# "Echo" in Low Pass Filter of an Image

Tags: java, image-processing, 2d, fft

I'm trying to implement a low pass spatial filter of an image in Java (using jTransforms) and I'm seeing some odd behaviour that I can't explain.

Everything works fine if I perform the FFT and then come straight back to the image, but when I try and put in the filter, I get an "echo" of the original outlines in the y-axis:

[image: Low pass filtered image showing "echo"]

If anyone could explain this I'd be very grateful! The filter I'm using is a simple step function.

Comment: Ringing is inherent property of ideal low pass filter. Examine the inverse of your filter in spatial domain and you see why. Better use Butterworth or Gaussian filter. The point spread function of latter is also Gaussian, so its the safest bet. What you have there looks like divergence (zeroes).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it can be that - ringing occurs near sharp transitions and manifests itself as an "outlining" of the object.

Comment: Show your code. Do you divide something? Artefacts near extrema look like numerical stability errors. But just using {1,0} ideal filter in freq domain wont do them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - twigged it. I wasn't dealing properly with the imaginary parts of the Fourier transform during the filtering. This was causing the echo when converted back to the spatial domain.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use a window function in the frequency domain you will get ringing artefacts, because step functions in the frequency domain become sinc functions in the spatial domain. In other words you can't just define a "brick wall" filter in the frequency domain without incurring nasty artefacts such as this.